# Drupal 8 custom place block pop-up result

Tags: 8, blocks

When go to Home > Administration  > Structure > **Block layout** page and click on **Place block** button, a pop-up appear with too many available blocks. Including some custom block types' content I wish to eliminate from this list.

So my question is it possible this pop-up list only display certain custom block type content, not all of them? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the only options are to replace the controller or alter the page.

Comment: There is an issue in CTools to fix this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2604178

Eventually such a solution could be moved to core.